# Easier method to solve composite function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

**Question**

> Let $f(x)=2x(x-2)$ where $x  \in [0,2]$. Find number of solutions of $f(f(f(x)))= \cfrac{x}{2}$

**My attempt**

I manually found $f(f(f(x)))$, drew its graph and $\frac{x}{2}$ and found the intersection points and got the answer which is 8. But it took a lot of time and we were supposed to do this Question in 3 minutes. Is there any simpler short method?

Comment: Intuitively speaking, $f(f(x))$ has degree $4$, and so $f(f(f(x))$ has degree $8$. $f(f(x))$ reaches its minimum value (which is the same as $f(x)$'s) $2$ times, and so $f(f(f(x)))$ reaches its minimum value $4$ times. Since $f^3 (x)$ is concave up, this gives you $8$ solutions in total.

Comment: In fact, all you need to show is that $y = \frac{x}{2}$ is not tangent to the critical points of $f^3 (x)$.